# jQuery removing/inserting DOM elements on scroll is finicky

Tags: jquery, webview, appcelerator

I'm building code for a web view in Appcelerator Titanium. Because of the massive (book length) size of the text on the webpage, I've built some jQuery to automatically remove/insert the page's content as the user scrolls. This means that only a small portion of the page is loaded at any given time, so there is a lot less stress on operating memory and much smoother rendering. Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// assign content index and parent, add to array

    var content = new Array();
    var index = 0;
    $('section > *').each(function() {
        // set variables
        var tag = $(this).get(0).tagName;
        var id = $(this).get(0).id;
        var style = $(this).get(0).className;
        var parent = $(this).parent('section').attr('index');
        var html = $(this).html();
        // add to html
        $(this).attr('parent', parent).attr('index', index);
        // add to array
        content[index] = new Array(tag, id, style, index, parent, html);
        // next index
        index++;
    });

// find center element, remove elements

    var midW = parseInt($(window).width() / 2);
    var midH = parseInt($(window).height() / 2);
    var centerEl = document.elementFromPoint(midW, midH);
    if (!$(centerEl).attr('parent')) {
        centerEl = $(centerEl).parent();
    }
    centerEl = parseInt($(centerEl).attr('index'));
    $('section > *').remove();

// insert content

    var firstEl = centerEl - 30;
    if (firstEl < 0) {
        firstEl = 0;
    }
    var lastEl = centerEl + 30;
    if (lastEl > content.length) {
        lastEl = content.length;
    }
    for (var i = firstEl; i < lastEl; i++) {
        var tag = content[i][0];
        var id = content[i][1];
        var style = content[i][2];
        var index = content[i][3];
        var parent = content[i][4];
        var html = content[i][5];
        var el = '<' + tag + ' id="' + id + '" class="' + style + '" index="' + index + '" parent="' + parent + '">' + html + '</' + tag + '>';
        $('section[index=' + parent + ']').append(el);
    }

// on scroll

var change;
var loadContent = function() {
    // find new center element
    midW = parseInt($(window).width() / 2);
    midH = parseInt($(window).height() / 2);
    newCenterEl = document.elementFromPoint(midW, midH);
    if (!$(newCenterEl).attr('parent')) {
        newCenterEl = $(newCenterEl).parent();
    }
    newCenterEl = parseInt($(newCenterEl).attr('index'));
    // if the center element has changed
    if (newCenterEl != centerEl) {
        // set center
        if (!isNaN(newCenterEl)) {
            change = newCenterEl - centerEl;
            centerEl = newCenterEl;
        }
        $('section > *').css('background-color', 'white'); // delete
        $('section > *[index=' + centerEl + ']').css('background-color', 'aqua'); // delete
        // calculate what to display
        var firstEl = centerEl - 30;
        if (firstEl < 0) {
            firstEl = 0;
        }
        var lastEl = centerEl + 30;
        if (lastEl > content.length) {
            lastEl = content.length;
        }
        // remove elements
        $('section > *').each(function() {
            var index = $(this).attr('index');
            if (index < firstEl || index > lastEl) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
        // add elements
        if (change > 0) {
            for (var i = firstEl; i <= lastEl; i++) {
                if ($('section > *[index=' + i + ']').length == 0) {
                    var tag = content[i][0];
                    var id = content[i][1];
                    var style = content[i][2];
                    var index = content[i][3];
                    var parent = content[i][4];
                    var html = content[i][5];
                    var el = '<' + tag + ' id="' + id + '" class="' + style + '" index="' + index + '" parent="' + parent + '">' + html + '</' + tag + '>';
                    $('section[index=' + parent + ']').append(el);
                }
            }
        }
        if (change < 0) {
            for (var i = lastEl; i >= firstEl; i--) {
                if ($('section > *[index=' + i + ']').length == 0) {
                    var tag = content[i][0];
                    var id = content[i][1];
                    var style = content[i][2];
                    var index = content[i][3];
                    var parent = content[i][4];
                    var html = content[i][5];
                    var el = '<' + tag + ' id="' + id + '" class="' + style + '" index="' + index + '" parent="' + parent + '">' + html + '</' + tag + '>';
                    $('section[index=' + parent + ']').prepend(el);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$(window).scroll(function() {
    loadContent();
});

});
```

Overall, it's working well, especially when the user scrolls down. Scrolling up also works, but for some reason it's much more finicky, and sometimes it gets stuck. The only major difference between scrolling up and scrolling down is that I'm prepending the content instead of appending it.

My question, then, is why might the upward scrolling be less reliable than the downward? Any thoughts/guesses/suggestions?

Comment: Just after I posted this, I tried loading 50 elements behind and 30 ahead, instead of 30 in each direction. Loading the extra elements behind seems to have resolved the finicky nature of the upward scrolling. I'm still not sure what the reason for this would be, so if anyone has insight, I'd appreciate it, but at least it's working smoothly now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I ended up with. It's working perfectly, and it's about a quarter of the size of the original code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// assign section IDs
    var sectionID = 0;
    $('section').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('id', 's' + sectionID);
        sectionID++;
    });

// assign element IDs, add to array
    var content = new Array();
    var contentID = 0;
    $('section > *').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('id', contentID);
        content[contentID] = new Array($(this).parent('section').attr('id'), $(this));
        contentID++;
    });

// display elements
    var display = function() {
        // determine center
        var center = parseInt($(document.elementFromPoint(parseInt($(window).width() / 2), parseInt($(window).height() / 2))).closest('section > *').attr('id'));
        // determine first/last
        var first, last;
        if (!isNaN(center)) {
            first = ((center - 20) < 0) ? 0 : (center - 20);
            last = ((center + 20) > content.length) ? content.length : (center + 20);
        }
        // hide
        $('section > *').each(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            if (id < first || id > last) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
        // show
        var start = $('section > *').first().attr('id') - 1;
        for (var i = start; i >= first; i--) {
            $('section#' + content[i][0]).prepend(content[i][1]);
        }
        var end = parseInt($('section > *').last().attr('id')) + 1;
        for (var i = end; i <= last; i++) {
            $('section#' + content[i][0]).append(content[i][1]);
        }
    }

// listeners
    $(window).load(function() {
        display();
    });
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        display();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is following:

prepending requires much more rendering efforts then appending, since all dom that goes after inserted element should be rebuilded. while appending there are no elements after inserted one

Anyway, jquery works MUCH faster if you prepend/append only once and not 50 times

```
for (var i = lastEl; i >= firstEl; i--) {
            if ($('section > *[index=' + i + ']').length == 0) {
                var tag = content[i][0];
                var id = content[i][1];
                var style = content[i][2];
                var index = content[i][3];
                var parent = content[i][4];
                var html = content[i][5];
                var el = '<' + tag + ' id="' + id + '" class="' + style + '" index="' + index + '" parent="' + parent + '">' + html + '</' + tag + '>';
                $('section[index=' + parent + ']').prepend(el);
            }
        }
```

you should rewrite this block, in order to minimize number of prepends

I suppose you dont have many sections, so you can do something like this

```
var sections={};
{ //your loop starts here

    if (typeof sections[parent]=='undefined'){
        sections[parent]=[];
    }
    var el=all+your+stuff;
    sections[parent].push(el);

}//ends here
$(sections).each(function(parent,section){
    $('section[index=' + parent + ']').prepend(section);    
});
```

i suppose you will change something, to adjust to your code, but this is idea -> minimize number of dom change operations, prepare bunch of elements and insert them alltogether

Comment: That's a great suggestion, thanks. I implemented it, and it did improve performance. Then I realized that I could seriously condense my code and reduce DOM changes by using the code I added below.